# How to auto-mount shared SMB folder on logon?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, samba

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

When I log on I see in the Files manager (near the bottom) this:

[image: Connect to server]

---

I routinely click "Connect to Server" and then see this:

[image: Shared folders list]

I then double-click those and they are mounted **without** needing a password to be entered, although the "nick" share in particular is set to have permissions for me only. The sharing is done by another PC running Ubuntu 14.04, and Samba shares (for compatibility with other PCs running Windows and OS/X).

---

**Question**: How do I have these actions performed automatically at logon?

---

I've seen [various suggestions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide) which usually involve editing a file `~/.smbcredentials` and putting my username and password in, like this:

```
username=foo
password=swordfish
```

Apart from the security concerns, I don't see why I should have to put my password in cleartext, when I can normally mount the shared folder without entering my password at all.

---

I note that when opening a file on this shared folder it doesn't appear to be in `/mnt` or `/media` but somewhere else entirely:

[image: Example of shared file]

Answer (score 2):

I've worked it out (I think). After reading about using `gvfs-mount` I found I could mount the share from the command line using:

```
gvfs-mount 'smb://10.0.0.2/nick/'
```

---

So now it was a case of doing that automatically. I used "Startup Applications" for this:

[image: Startup Applications]

---

Then I added an entry for each desired disk:

[image: Disks to mount]

---

Each entry looked like this:

[image: Mount one disk]

That seems to work fine.

---

### Edit

Following on from a comment, change from "gvs-mount" to "gio mount" instead, as gvs-mount is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked and answered a long time ago, but I came to it as I had that exact problem.

Currently, `gvfs-mount` is deprecated.
You should follow the start-up answer but you should use `gio mount` :

```
gio mount 'smb://10.0.0.2/nick/'
```

I hope that is going to help someone.

Comment: Thanks! My solution would have eventually stopped working and I would have wondered why. I'll amend the answer.